# Temporarily plug kitchen faucet spray hose inlet

Tags: faucet, sink

Through a comedy of errors the connectors for the tubing  beneath my faucet were thrown away.  These are custom connectors.  I managed to pick up new connectors for the faucet (hot and cold to spout) but was not able to get a connector to the sprayer.  As a result, if I turn on the water valves, water will shoot out of the hole where the sprayer used to be connected.

Is there a sensible way to temporarily and reversably plug the sprayer inlet piping (pictured) so I can use my faucet and dishwasher until the new sprayer assembly arrives on Tuesday?  Recall this fitting is not threaded and so the patch would have to fit inside or wrap around the outside.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Pipe clamp around a rubber sheet?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to see the size but something like a peice of a garage hose and a gear clamp would do the trick.

This is a gear clamp with a handle [image]https://www.mscdirect.com

One with a handle will be helpful because it's tight up there. Cut a section of garden hose, gear clamp it on with one of these

Female hose cap[image]www.homedepot.com

Or a variation of this concept. 
P.S. I would advise against leaving a temporary water solution like this unattended. Shut off the water if you are leaving.